# Parallelise enumerate loop with `multiprocessing` module

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

My code looks like that:

```
# Features' construction - Multiprocessing #
import pandas as pd
import time
import multiprocessing



def features_construct(index, row):

    dict_features ={}

    ...

    return(dict_features)


data = []
for index, row in enumerate(raw_data):

    data.append(features_construct(index, row))


df_data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

`raw_data` is a list of two-element lists where each element is a json.

How can I parallelise this code with `python`'s `multiprocessing` module?

Answer (score 1):

Run:

```
import multiprocessing

output=[]

raw_data = [[2,2],[4,3],[5,1],[6,3],[7,2],[12,4],[12,2]]


def features_construct(index, row):

    dict_features ={}

    ...

    return(dict_features)

def combinations():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(64)
    outputs=pool.starmap(features_construct, raw_data)
    ### check starmap above

    return outputs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output.append(combinations())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I receive this error: `TypeError: features_construct() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'` which is quite resonable since I do not see where you pass the arguments for `features_construct`.

Comment: @Poete, please add your complete code for the function `def features_construct(index, row):`.

Comment: My complete code is really long and it is not required for you to understand how the multiprocessing code should be written. It is enough if you know that I use the index and the element (from the `enumerate`) in my `feature-construct` code. As I wrote you at my comment above, I do not get an error in the code of `feature_construct` but exactly before this starts because I have not simply passed the required arguments to the function ;)

Comment: Fixed. Check it now @Poete

Comment: That's better but now I get an error in my code at my first feature (and at the first iteration): ` File "<ipython-input-12-43fcff50f381>", line 54, in features_construct
    dict_features['feature_1_{}'.format(i+1)] = len(row[i]['text'])
KeyError: 0`. Just to make clear that I was not getting any error and certainly not a `KeyError` at my original code. As far as I understand the error occurs when the program substistutes `row[i]` with `row[0]` and it does not find that but according to my original code this is impossible. So I am not sure that `starmap` passes what we want.

Comment: Or if you tell me exactly what `starmap` passes then I may modify a bit my code although the same error will occur in all my features construction because the same indexing occurs at all of them.

Comment: Hm actually I see what you do. I will have a look at it later or tomorrow and I will tell you if it finally worked by changing also a bit my code. (Upvote for your time here ;) )

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution but not multiprocessing the module with multi-thread also can improve the speed.

Here is code with enumerate in multi-thread:

```py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from datasets.config import GlobalConfig

# The initial data operations are done in the get_item of the dataset
from datasets.dataloader import CARLA_Data
# The initial data operations are done in the get_item of the dataset

import ray
ray.init()
sample_in_pre_run = 50
@ray.remote(num_cpus=48)
def write_pkl(save_dir, cur_num, dataset, run_num):
    # print(cur_num, cur_num + run_num)
    for i in range(cur_num, min(cur_num + run_num, len(dataset))):
        with open(f'{save_dir}/%d.pkl'%(i), 'wb') as fd:
            pickle.dump(dataset[i], fd)

ray_train_set = ray.put(train_set)
for cur_num in range(0, len(train_set), sample_in_pre_run):
      tasks_pre.append(write_pkl.remote(train_dir, cur_num, ray_train_set, sample_in_pre_run))
ray_val_set = ray.put(val_set)
for cur_num in range(0, len(val_set), sample_in_pre_run):
    tasks_pre.append(write_pkl.remote(val_dir, cur_num, val_set, sample_in_pre_run))

# together
ray.get(tasks_pre)
```

And with the proper tune on the thread, the speed can faster twice or ten in some computers.

Here is the ray tutorial on multi-thread: https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/walkthrough.html

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I just find the solution... with multi-thread, previous is just save this question to see if I will find the solution.